# Simple Objective-C command line code runs fine in terminal, breaks in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm working my way through *Programming in Objective-C* by Stephen Kochan, and have come unstuck with one of the exercises, namely to create a class for 2D coordinate values. My code runs fine using the Xcode command line tools, however it appears to break if I try to run the same program in Xcode itself.

main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

//--- @interface section ---
@interface Cartesian: NSObject

-(void) setCoordinateX: (int) x;
-(void) setCoordinateY: (int) y;
-(int) coordinateX;
-(int) coordinateY;
-(void) print;

@end

//--- @implementation section ---
@implementation Cartesian
{
    int coordinateX;
    int coordinateY;
}

-(void) setCoordinateX: (int) x
{
    coordinateX = x;
} // Xcode highlights this row as green (breakpoint)

-(void) setCoordinateY: (int) y
{
    coordinateY = y;
}

-(int) coordinateX
{
    return coordinateX;
}

-(int) coordinateY
{
    return coordinateY;
}

-(void) print
{
    NSLog(@"This coordinate value is (%i,%i)", coordinateX, coordinateY);
}

@end

//--- program section ---
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        Cartesian *point1 = [Cartesian new];

        [point1 setCoordinateX: 3];
        [point1 setCoordinateY: 4];

        [point1 print];
        NSLog(@"To reiterate, this coordinate value is (%i,%i)", [point1 coordinateX], [point1 coordinateY]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me understand
1. What has gone wrong?
2. Why this would run fine in Terminal using the Xcode command line tools?

Comment: Apologies - Xcode now seems to be running this absolutely fine, no hiccups. I guess my question should actually be: is this inconsistent behaviour Xcode's fault, or mine?

Comment: what changes did you make for this to run ok ?

Comment: @jsedano Originally I didn't think I'd made any changes, although Sulthan's (accepted) answer suggests I probably added/removed a manual breakpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have actually added a manual breakpoint

[image]

Double tap (option tap) it and remove it or just drag and drop it outside your window.

Breakpoints are a way to tell the application to stop when a condition (or line of code) is reached. You can use them to inspect the state of the application, inspect variables, step through your code etc. One of the most important things when debugging applications.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what happened (arrow looks familiar). Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

In some situations, your code may break in Xcode, because the actual compiler flags that are passed by Xcode is usually way more complicated than just simply typing gcc or clang in your terminal.

In this case, you would have to provide us with the line that is throwing error in Xcode in order to see what can be fixed.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. The line throwing the error is `coordinateX = x;` in the implementation section. However, it is no longer throwing that error, despite my not having touched the code (except to copy it, for the purposes of this post).